# Who is Moloch relative to the devil?

Tags: sleepy-hollow

Does Moloch work on behalf of the devil (Satan, whatever) to bring about Armageddon? Where does he come in relative to canonical biblical stories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Who Moloch is, what his plans are and his relationship, if any, to the Fallen Angel, Lucifer (a.k.a Satan) is as yet unrevealed in the television series, 'Sleepy Hollow'.

- Moloch, "the God Demon of Child Sacrifice", is the main antagonist of the series of Sleepy Hollow, with the goal to bring forward the Apocalypse. As such, he was responsible for the raising of the Headless Horseman.

**However:**

- Moloch is the name of an ancient Ammonite god. Moloch worship was practiced by the Canaanites, Phoenicians, and related cultures in North Africa and the Levant. Moloch makes his appearance as a demon in Paradise Lost but appears much earlier in Leviticus as a bull-headed god whom Yahweh warned the Cannanites to stop worshipping. Multiple spellings of this dark deity's origins Molech, Molek, Molok, make tracking him difficult.
- Religiously speaking there is probably no relationship between Lucifer and Moloch which is why Sleepy Hollow's use of him is both novel and unusual.

**[Entertainment Weekly](http://insidetv.ew.com/2013/12/04/crazy-ones-mom-sleepy-hollow-second-chance-reviews/) summed the show up like this:**

> **Why We Doubted It**
>
> From the start, Sleepy Hollow was full of polished, poppy lunacy. The Headless Horseman with a machine gun! George Washington, Apocalypse Slayer! But the premise — buddy cops battling the end times in a small town — seemed limited. How long before the fish-out-of-water humor of man-out-of-time Ichabod Crane (Tom Mison) got old? And the Headless Horseman with a machine gun? That’s not a villain with legs, let alone a brain.
>
> **How It Surprised Us**
>
> Two words: Nicole Beharie. Her turn as Ichabod’s partner/modern-times tutor grounds the gonzo with humanity, and her chemistry with Mison makes them pure fun to be around. A team of compelling Armageddon resistance fighters is emerging — John Noble’s sin eater is a nice addition — and the mythology is harebrained fun. The Boston Tea Party was really about stealing a portal to hell?! Revolutionary indeed. B+

- Sleepy Hollow is a pastiche of themes, ideas, and legendary concepts smashed together in an oddly satisfying manner. The show's producers admit they are willing to mix and match ideas in order to tell satisfying stories, which is their primary goal.
- Like Supernatural, I wouldn't expect too much in the way of organization or relationship to well-known mythoi or other Biblical tales.